# Saving a Word Document with a Excel Cell Reference : VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Currently I am copying an active excel sheet and saving the data from this active excel spreadsheet to a pre-formatted word document.
This pre-formatted word document then gets saved with a specific file name.

In the initial VBA setup i have declared a variable called `myfilename` which contains a date value. (01022019)

What I would like to learn is how I can concatenate the `myfilename` value with the saved filename using the `SaveAs` command as shown in the code. For example the saved file would be test 01022019. This is a straightforward task when saving an Excel Spreadsheet using VBA but not so when saving a word document using VBA.

I have attached some code in the hope I can get a solution:

```
Sub SaveAsWord()


Dim LastRow As Long
Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
Dim myfilename As String
myfilename = Sheets("Import").Range("B2")



Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wordApp.Documents.Open "C:\test\test\worddocument.docx"
wordApp.Visible = True

With wDoc

wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="C:\test\test.docx"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Concatenation using `&` is the same in Word and Excel. Assuming you've tried that, are you getting an error?

Comment: If i use wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="C:\test\test & myfilename.docx  the result is test&myfilename.docx  not the value in B2

Comment: `FileName:="C:\test\test " & myfilename & ".docx"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `&` to conctenate the path(String) and the filename (Variable) as shown below. Also you need to specify the FileFormat.

Try this

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\test\test\" & myfilename & ".docx", _
                               FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
```

or

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\test\test" & myfilename & ".docx", _
                               FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
```

Choose one from above based on the location where you want to save it.

If you are late binding then then declare this at the very top.

```
Const wdFormatXMLDocument as Integer = 12
```

Comment: using the code provided worked !! - initially i had a problem but it was due to a incorrect Data Format that i used as the myfilename string